# Is there a way to implement server side verification in google admob using react-native/expo and not android only?

Tags: react-native, admob, expo, server-side-validation

I'm developing a expo/react-native app.
I want to use google admob inside my app (rewarded ads, videos), and verify in my server (node.js) if the user did finish the ad.

I saw in the website of google admob that there is a way to verify this in android. This is the link: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video-ssv
But I could not find anywhere, a way to verify it in react-native/expo app. (with node.js server).

I want to know if this is possible, and if so what is the best way to do it.

Comment: When you've finished viewing the ad through communication with the node server, pass on the value.

Comment: I did not understand. Do you mean that while he is watching I should send messages to the server that he is watching?

Comment: Communicate with the server when the person through Event Lister has finished advertising.

Comment: Oh now I understood. But this is my question. If I will send post request to my server to inform it that the user finished the as, he can do it as well. He can "fake" the post request. Therefor, I want also server side verification.

Comment: @OmerLevi Did you find any way to do that ?

Comment: Nope. Still looking

Comment: https://github.com/encerge/admob-rewarded-ads-ssv